# CSS Transitions not working

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a container system that only shows/hides one menu at a time.  It works for the most part, but I can't get the CSS transitions to work correctly.  I've been looking at this for a couple hours and can't figure out why there are no transitions occurring at all.

The menu needs to drop down and scroll back up when a container is clicked.  I just need a starting point on getting some kind of transition to occur when the user clicks a container.

CSS:

```
.singledrop {
    display: none;
}
.singledroplabel h2 {
    display: inline;
    color: #4e4e50;
}
.singledrop+.content {
    display: none;
    height: 0px;
    transition: height 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: height 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: height 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.singledrop:checked+.content {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <label class="singledroplabel" for="drop1"><h2>Foo</h2></label>
    <input class="singledrop" type="radio" name="menu" id="drop1" />
    <div class="content">
        foo<br/>
        foo<br/>
        foo<br/>
        foo<br/>
        foo<br/>
        foo<br/>
        foo<br/>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <label class="singledroplabel" for="drop2"><h2>Bar</h2></label>
    <input class="singledrop" type="radio" name="menu" id="drop2" />
    <div class="content">
        bar<br/>
        bar<br/>
        bar<br/>
        bar<br/>
        bar<br/>
        bar<br/>
        bar<br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't animate to `height:auto`. Try hardcoding a height, or setting `max-height` to something huge.

http://jsfiddle.net/adambiggs/MAbD3/

is a good example of the max-height method.